# Trained Logistic Regression returns 'NAN' for some out of sample data

Tags: logistic, svm, matlab, binary-data, separation

I'm using `MATLAB R2015a`, `glmfit` function for training and `glmval` for out of sample evaluation. My input sample and out-of-sample are normalized (MAX-MIN mapping / Using MAX-MIN of training sample set for normalizing out-of-sample data set).

When I'm suing `SVM` or `MLP` model there isn't any problem and I have output values for all out-of-samples but when I check Logistic Regression outputs, in some samples I have `NAN` as output.

[image]

In cases that we have `NAN` as output, all inputs are negative (or many of them) as we can see in above picture. The above data set is out-of-sample that we used to predict output probabibites after model training phase. Why Logistic Regression returns `Nan` output for these samples?

**PS.** In training phase I have this error :

```
Warning: Iteration limit reached.
```

Model information :

```
log Likelihood : -1.2241758
SST = 80
SSR = 40.5388
DFE = 307


Estimated Coefficients:
                   Estimate      SE        tStat        pValue  
                   ________    _______    ________    __________

    (Intercept)      2.0485    0.40146      5.1027    3.3484e-07
    x1              -6.5222     1.4907     -4.3751    1.2136e-05
    x2               1.3972     0.3009      4.6434    3.4269e-06
    x3              -8.7807     2.7749     -3.1644     0.0015542
    x4               96.094     180.41     0.53265       0.59427
    x5             0.042014    0.77166    0.054446       0.95658
    x6             -0.75486    0.72205     -1.0454       0.29582
    x7               1.1678    0.98433      1.1864       0.23548
    x8               1.9328    0.73925      2.6146     0.0089338
    x9             -0.65827     0.2902     -2.2683       0.02331
    x10             -102.83     180.47    -0.56982        0.5688
    x11              1.3374    0.62117      2.1531      0.031311
    x12            -0.43609    0.61412    -0.71011       0.47764


320 observations, 307 error degrees of freedom
Dispersion: 1
Chi^2-statistic vs. constant model: 199, p-value = 5.83e-36
```

Comment: Some more detail would help - a grid of numbers without headers isn't easily interpretable. What's the value of -34.5598 you've put a box round? - a log-odds ratio for one predictor? the overall linear predictor? What's "output"? - the predicted probabilities for the training set? test set?

Comment: @Scortchi .Thank you for your comment. I added some information to the question.

Comment: Thanks, but there's still very little to go on. Suggestion: check for complete or quasi-complete separation in the training set - the error message suggests the regression algorithm didn't converge on a maximum-likelihood solution. `NaN`s ought then to be `0` or `1`.

Comment: @Scortchi. I'm using 10-fold cross validation in my estimating. So you think my sample can't meet assumption of logistic regression? So we have better results in `SVM` and `MLP` without `NAN` outputs?

Comment: No, I think the code you're running isn't dealing correctly with very large or very small estimated coefficients.

Comment: @Scortchi. So you think this is a `MATLAB` problem that can't handle these out of range values? Is any link between above error massege and `NAN` outputs?

Comment: For the statistical issue (if I guessed right) see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124616), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45803), & [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102695) for what it is & how to check for it, & [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109) for ways to deal with it. For Matlab-specific issues there is a list of support sites [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/).

Comment: Re your edit: if the very large coefficient values are also accompanied by very large standard errors, that would be strongly symptomatic of separation.

Comment: So then, x4 & x10 - plot them against the response to visualize what's going on. Recall that the coefficient estimates are *log*-odds ratios, so very big/small indeed once you exponentiate them.